# Loop input fields and hide using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bigcommerce

I have a page that has some input fields that are dynamically created. I need to loop through the inputs comparing the value. If the value matches the needle(value searching for) then the input and its label need to be hidden. Below is an example from the page:

**Needle:** value=5762

````
<div id="AOSwatch" class="form-field" data-product-attribute="swatch">
    <label class="form-label form-label--alternate form-label--inlineSmall">
        Color:
        <span data-option-value></span>

            <small>Required</small>
    </label>

        <input class="form-radio AOformswatch" type="radio" name="attribute[1471]" value="5761" id="attribute_swatch_1471_5761"  required>
        <label class="form-option form-option-swatch" for="attribute_swatch_1471_5761" data-product-attribute-value="5761">
                        <span class='form-option-variant form-option-variant--color' title="Black" style="background-color: #252525"></span>
        </label>
        <input class="form-radio AOformswatch" type="radio" name="attribute[1471]" value="5762" id="attribute_swatch_1471_5762"  required>
        <label class="form-option form-option-swatch" for="attribute_swatch_1471_5762" data-product-attribute-value="5762">
                        <span class='form-option-variant form-option-variant--color' title="Brown" style="background-color: #5A442D"></span>
        </label>
        <input class="form-radio AOformswatch" type="radio" name="attribute[1471]" value="5763" id="attribute_swatch_1471_5763"  required>
        <label class="form-option form-option-swatch" for="attribute_swatch_1471_5763" data-product-attribute-value="5763">
                        <span class='form-option-variant form-option-variant--color' title="Navy" style="background-color: #1C3A6C"></span>
        </label>
</div>```

How would I do this using javascript? I already have some other javascript loading on the page, I think I'm just looking for a function or some code to loop through and do the hiding.

Thanks for any help or thoughts.
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**jQuery:**

You iterate through all the `input`s, and if you find one whose value matches the target value, you apply `display: none` to it. Then you also find a label whose attribute matches the value, and you do the same.

```
var targetValue = 5762;
$("#AOSwatch").find("input").each(function(){
  if($(this).val() === targetValue){
      $(this).css("display", "none");
      $("#AOSwatch").find("label[data-product-attribute-value='"+targetValue+"']").css("display", "none");
  }
});
```